# Rails 4 Flash messages: Random messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In the quest of making the experience for a project I am working on a little bit more enjoyable for the user, I want to implement changing flash messages.

Besides that, I would also clean up my Controller a little. Right now, all of my flash messages are hard coded in to the `EntriesController` which makes things messy. Ideally I'd like to achieve two things:

- Move flash messages for :success, :danger and :info in to a separate file to to clean up my controller (and it will probably be necessary for running rand over the hash)
- Call the flash message type hash and run something like `.shuffle` over it to pick a random message.

How is this being ideally achieved?

Comment: What random messages do you want to output? Are they tied to objects / functionality, or just greeting messages?

Comment: @RichPeck – good question. They are actually tied to functionality. I want a set of success messages for a successful login. I also want a set of success messages for a successful post. Since they have different wording, those will be separate messages.

Comment: What's wrong with explicitly defining them in their respective controller actions?

Comment: Nothing wrong in particular – I'd just like to make the code a bit slicker and make it easier to add new flash messages.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a helper for your flashes, store them all in the en.yml file, and use them in your controller like this with the `.sample` method

```
# app/controllers/entries_controller.rb
include FlashHelpers
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    flash_message success_flashes.sample if success?
    # and so on ...
  end
end

# app/helpers/flash_helpers.rb
module FlashHelpers
  def flash_message(message)
    flash[:message] = message
  end

  def success_flashes
    flash_messages.fetch :success
  end

  def danger_flashes
    flash_messages.fetch :danger
  end

  def info_flashes
    flash_messages.fetch :info
  end

  private

  def flash_messages
    I18n.translate("flash_messages")
  end      
end

# app/views/some_view
<%= flash[:message] %>


# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  flash_messages:
    info:
    - info1 message
    - info2 message
    - info3 message
    danger:
    - danger1 message
    - danger2 message
    - danger3 message
    success:
    - success1 message
    - success2 message
    - success3 message
```

Comment: If you find it helpful plz consider giving my answer an upvote and accepted answer.

Comment: Did you find this helpful? I took time to write this. Consider an upvote and/or accepted answer plz